# Accessing Inner Array Values Properly With ForEach() - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have

```js
b = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6];

b.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach(element => element += 2)
    }
    else {
        value += 2;
    }
    console.log(`The value at ${index} is ${value}`);
})
```

And I'm wondering why this is logging

> The value at 3 is 4,5

Instead of

> The value at 3 is 6, 7

I thought I'd accessed the inner array by checking if the value is an array, and then I did another `.forEach` loop to access each element of that inner-array?

Trying to fully understand `.forEach()` in JS. Thanks!

Comment: After the loop, do you expect `b[0]` to be 1 or 3? (Not the output, the value in `b` after the loop has completed.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wasn't trying to alter the original values of the array, just the output values. So in this case I was just expecting `b[0]` to still equal 1.

Comment: Though seeing how to alter the values of the original array is also helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two reasons:

1. `forEach` completely ignores the value you return from its callback
2. You never do anything to update `value`

If you want to modify `value`, you'd either do this:

```
value = value.map(element => element + 2);
```

...which creates a *new* array and assigns it to `value`; note that `b` is completely unaffected. (This is just like your `value += 2` in the other branch, which also doesn't affect `b` at all.) Live example:

```js
const b = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6];

b.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value = value.map(element => element + 2);
    }
    else {
        value += 2;
    }
    console.log(`The value at ${index} is ${value}`);
})
// Just to show that `b` is unaffected:
console.log(`b[3] = ${b[3]}`);
```

Or this:

```
value.forEach((element, index) => {
    value[index] = element + 2;
});
```

...which changes the original array (inside `b`), which **doesn't** match the `else` branch (which doesn't update `b`). Live example:

```js
const b = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6];

b.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach((element, index) => {
            value[index] = element + 2;
        });
    }
    else {
        value += 2;
    }
    console.log(`The value at ${index} is ${value}`);
})
// Just to show that `b` is modified:
console.log(`b[3] = ${b[3]}`);
```

**But**, if you want to modify `b`, you should probably do it consistently. [Kobe posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56362805/157247) how you'd do that with `map`, which creates a new array and is often what you want. If you wanted to update the existing array instead, then:

```js
const b = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6];
for (const [bIndex, value] of b.entries()) {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        for (const [vIndex, entry] of value.entries()) {
            value[vIndex] = entry + 2;
        }
    } else {
        b[bIndex] = value + 2;
    }
}
console.log(`b = ${JSON.stringify(b)}`);
```

...but [Kobe's `map` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56362805/157247) is usually what I'd reach for unless I had a good reason to update in place.

Answer (score 1):

You are editing the property, not the value, but then you are not storing the new property anywhere. You should reference the value you are logging, not the properties:

```js
b = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6];

b.forEach((value, index) => {
    if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach((element, i) => value[i] += 2)
    } else {
        value += 2;
    }
    console.log(`The value at ${index} is ${value}`);
})
```

Should you want to avoid writing this, you should use map to return a new array with the modified values:

```js
b = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6];

b = b.map(value => Array.isArray(value) ? value.map(el => el + 2) : value + 2)

console.log(b)
```

Comment: This modifies `b` when the entry is an array, but not when it isn't. The OP didn't tell us what they want us to do, but given the `value += 2` in the `else`, probably best not to modify `b` in the `if` branch either.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're correct. I'll leave it as is, but if it's an issue ill remove it.

Comment: They wanted to leave `b` alone, but this is still helpful for others.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Cheers mate, I edited my answer so as not to mutate the original array